# How to use command line argument with awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

my file format is like this

```
#id|lastName|firstName|gender|
```

my script is this

```
#!/bin/bash

 while getopts ":f:i:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
       f)
         file=${OPTARG}
         awk -F'|' '{print}' ./dates.dat
         ;;
       i)
         id=${OPTARG}
         awk -v var=${OPTARG} -F'|' '$1==var {print $2,$3}' ./dates.dat
         ;;
    esac
  done
 shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

The proble is that with the line

```
awk -v var=${OPTARG} -F'|' '$1==var {print $2,$3}' ./dates.dat
```

I want to print the last name and first name when i give a number for id as an argument in the command line.Instead i get nothing

Comment: It looks as if you misspelled `var` as `car`.

Comment: BTW, you never use `$file` in the first case.

Comment: And you never use `$id` in the second case.

Comment: Misspelled it here but not in the original code

Comment: This works fine, are you sure that `$OPTARG` contains a value? Example: `printf '1|foo|bar|baz\n2|FOO|BAR|BAZ\n' | awk -F '|' -v var=2 '$1==var {print $2,$3}'`

Comment: how do you call the script, are you sure you're passing the arguments?  there is no error check or catch all in case statement.

Comment: You aren't passing an unquoted argument that starts with '#' are you? :)

Comment: The command I give is:  ./tool.sh -f dates.dat -id 106492658 . Then it prints the whole file( that's what happens with the f case) but not the specific fields from the awk command in the i case. The argument is an id number that exists in the file .

Comment: If you run the script with `bash -x yourscript ...args...` you can see how `awk` is *actually* invoked. That's a good place to start, to figure out of the problem is on the bash side or the awk side (f/e, whether the parameter in hand is actually passed to awk at all). BTW, quotes matter -- `-v var="$OPTARG"` works with variable content with spaces, and in some other cases where the shell will otherwise invoke `awk` in a manner that's other than what you want.

Comment: With the bash wrapper as shown, if you pass both -f and -id, two awks will run, one after the other.